# Why should i use modules in JavaScript and not just use classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im playing around with JavaScript (ES6) and I'm trying to understand why I would use modules. I understand what they do (sort of) but a question that keeps lingering in my mind is why would i use modules and not just reference the .js files that contains my classes? Example: I have a class "car" saved in a file "car.js". In that file i export the class. And now in my web site i import my module. Why wouldn't i just reference the car.js file. What do i get extra / achieve by having it as a module?

Comment: While you can certainly do that on the web, you cannot do that in other JS environments (e.g. Node). Modules allow you to maintain your code better. Imports are colocated with where they actually used. If you only include files on your webpage then you have to make sure the files are loaded in the correct order and all the dependencies of a file are loaded. Because each file shares the same global scope the relationship is implicit, not explicit. Imagine you include 100 JS files in the page, would you still know each files dependencies after 3 months?

Comment: Good point about other environments - and the concerns about the number of files has also bothered me.

Comment: You're considering the case with a single file and a single class, which is really bad example. What if there are tire.js, wheel.js and driver.js as well that depend on each other in some way? Should all of them be loaded with <script>? In which order? Then the classes have to be exposed as globals to be used by other classes, right?